# Filtering a Feature Class in using ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, arcgis-flex-api

I'm using the following code in Flex to display all the features in a Feature Class defined in the "Data Layer".

```
var dataLayer:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer= map.getLayer("Data Layers") as ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer;
var dataLayerId:int;

dataLayerId = 5;

dataLayer.visibleLayers.removeAll();
dataLayer.visibleLayers.addItem(dataLayerId);
dataLayer.refresh();
```

But I'd like to apply a filter like "WHERE MGD = 1" (MGD is an attribute defined in the feature class) to display only a subset of that feature class. 
Any help or autosuggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: According to the description I think you need to use Layer Definitions  example (http://help.arcgis.com/en/webAPI/flex/samples/index.html#/Use_Layer_Definitions/01nq00000029000000/) I assume that you are applying filer to dynamic layer..thanks..

Comment: + you are using sql server tag so are you using query layer ? if yes then you can insert the filter in query itself (example http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_is_a_query_layer/00s50000000n000000/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Sunil's comments, the following is the right code to answer my question:

```
            var dataLayer:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer= map.getLayer("Data Layers") as ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer;
            var dataLayerId:int;
            var layerDefs:Array = new Array();

            dataLayerId = 5;

            dataLayer.visibleLayers.removeAll();
            dataLayer.visibleLayers.addItem(dataLayerId);
            layerDefs = [];
            layerDefs[dataLayerId] = " MGD = 1 " 
            dataLayer.layerDefinitions = layerDefs; 
            dataLayer.refresh();
```